# Laravel Route to delete with Javascript/Bootstrap Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I wrote a formular in Laravel ( PHP Framework ) and this formular gets some data and send them with a route to my controller. My Controller have the function to delete the datas from the Database. Well now I want a javascript/Bootstrap checkbox and found this:

```
        <script>
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
                Example.show("Confirm result: "+result);
            });
        </script>
```

There is a life test for this code here: http://bootboxjs.com

Now I want to connect this code with my laravel formular. Could somebody help me there? I really don't work much with javascript..

thanks!

Formular:

```
            {!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroy", $thread->id)) !!}
            {!! Former::large_danger_submit('Delete') !!} 
            {!! Former::close() !!}
```

current code:

```
{!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroy", $thread->id))->id('conf') !!}
            {!! Former::large_danger_submit('Delete') !!}
            <script>
                $('.conf').submit(function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var subm = confirm("Are you sure?");
                    if(subm){
                        $('.conf p').text('Pressed Ok');
                        this.submit();
                    }else{
                        $('.conf p').text('Pressed Cancel');
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            </script>
            {!! Former::close() !!}
```

getting j.query, javascript and bootstrap like this:

whole master.blade.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    @include("elements.navbar")
    <div class="container">
        <hr />

        @yield('content')
        <hr />
    </div>
@yield('custom-script')
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the HTML with the form and the JS confirm code of course getting the data of the master.blade.php. So query and JS/Bootstrap are supported.

Comment: or maybe another way for a confirm..

Answer (score 0):

```
**Jquery required.**
```

Another way without bootbox

```
<html>
    <head>
       //head
    </head>
    <body>
        @include("elements.navbar")
        <div class="container">
            <hr />
            @yield('content')
            <hr />
        </div>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        @yield('custom-script')
    </body>
</html>
```

Your form view

```
{!! Former::horizontal_open()->method('DELETE')->action(action("Test\\TestController@destroy", $thread->id))->id('conf') !!}
    {!! Former::large_danger_submit('Delete') !!}
{!! Former::close() !!}
@section('custom-script')
<script>
//DOM Ready
$(function(){
    $('#conf').submit(function(event) {//form ID (not Class as you have ->id('conf'))
        event.preventDefault();
        var subm = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if(subm){
            console.log('Press Ok')
            this.submit();
        }else{
            console.log('Press Cancel')
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
@stop
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpuf3u0n/)

Comment: well, I need to take the way without bootbox because I haven't the package for bootbox.. I installed Jquery but bootbox isn't in there.. could you tell me how I can connect the seccond way with my formular? like if its true, go to the destroy method in my controller, otherwise do nothing?

I dont know, JS confuse me

Comment: okay it's now in the form, I dont get any erros, the thread just will be deleted. And Jquery is loading before Javascript in my network console -- and I just need a normal confirm, if its true, I will get redirected to another site

Comment: I mean, if the confirmation gives true ( pressed okay ) then I will get redirect to another site. Otherwise nothing will happen. Thats the only thing I want to get

Comment: tried this too, but it still does the same, just delete the thread and thats all, no confirm :/ it works in Fiddle.. thats why I think there is a problem with my form. I will update my question with my form and some other things